# What Text-To-Speech API (TTS) services exist?

Tags: api, text-to-speech, saas

I want to run text-to-speech conversion on my server using a service over an API.

Google Text-To-Speech (TTS) is not available for this now.  What alternatives are available (both paid and free)?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a selection of RESTful service providers that I know of.

- [Cereproc](https://www.cereproc.com/en/products/cloud)
- [Ivona](https://www.ivona.com/us/for-business/speech-cloud/)
- [iSpeech](http://www.ispeech.org/)
- [Nuance](https://developer.nuance.com)
- [Microsoft (Project Oxford)](https://github.com/Microsoft/ProjectOxford-clientsdk)
- [Watson](https://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/text-to-speech.html)
- [Neo](http://neospeech.com/)
- [Acapela](http://www.acapela-group.com/)
- [AT&T](https://developer.att.com/apis/speech/docs) (think this is closed to new users now)

There are others, some free - but lower quality. You get what you pay for...